# Unable to display and update my location marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use geolocation to determine the user locationa and updated it periodically. In addition to my location, other markers are displayed on the map.
I'm currently unable to display the my location marker and get this error from google maps API **InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama.**

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Google maps</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

           var lat, lon, mapCalled, mapoptions, position, oldPosition, currentposition, iconBase, watchPositionOptions, geoToken, myLocationSymbol, ischiaCenter, myLocationMarker, homeMap, walk1Start, myScroll, errorMsg;
oldPosition = null;


function onBodyLoad(mapP){
    mapCalled = mapP;
    console.log(mapCalled);
    ischiaCenter = new google.maps.LatLng (40.727954, 13.903094);   
    console.log("ischia center" + ischiaCenter);
    console.log("before position is asked");
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError);
    console.log("heading getting heading");
     mapoptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: ischiaCenter,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    createMapHome();
}

function onGeoSuccess(position) {
    console.log("starting watch");
     navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onGeoWatchSuccess, onGeoError, {maximumAge: 4000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
    setCurrentPosition(position);
    }

function onGeoWatchSuccess(position) {
    console.log("geosuccess");
    setMarkerPosition(myLocationMarker, position); 
}

function setCurrentPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    currentposition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
    console.log("currentposition " + currentposition);
    /*Create marker for user current position*/
    console.log("Updating location");
    myLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: currentposition,
        map: mapCalled
    });   
    console.log("panning to my location");
    mapCalled.panTo(currentposition);
}

function setMarkerPosition(myLocationMarker, position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    currentposition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
    myLocationMarker.setPosition(currentposition);
    }

function createMapHome(){
 //   geoToken = 1;
    console.log("creating home map");
    homeMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapoptions);
    /*Create marker for walks starting points with info dialog*/

    var walk1Start = new google.maps.LatLng (59.32522, 18.07002);

    var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div class="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Walk1</h2>'+
        '<img src="images/thumbs/G-87.jpg" width=150 height=150>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p>Prima linea di decrizione ' +
        'Senconda linea di decrizione '+
        'Heritage Site.</p>'+

        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    var walk1Marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
        position: walk1Start,
        map: homeMap,
        title: "Walk 1"
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(walk1Marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(homeMap,walk1Marker);
    });

    /*Script to adjust map view to all markers*/

    //  Make an array of the LatLng's of the markers you want to show
    var LatLngList = new Array ( ischiaCenter, walk1Start);
    //  Create a new viewpoint bound
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
    //  Go through each...
    for (var i = 0, LtLgLen = LatLngList.length; i < LtLgLen; i++) {
        //  And increase the bounds to take this point
        bounds.extend (LatLngList[i]);
    }
    //  Fit these bounds to the map
    homeMap.fitBounds (bounds);

    center = homeMap.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(homeMap, "resize");
    homeMap.setCenter(center);
}


/*Setting up alerts*/

function showAlert (message, title) {
        if (navigator.notification) {
            navigator.notification.alert(message, null, title, 'OK');
        } else {
            alert(title ? (title + ": " + message) : message);
        }
    }


    function onGeoError(error) {
        console.log("geo error", error.code);
        if (error.code==1) {
            showAlert ('Abbiamo bisogno di accedere alla tua posizione. Attiva i servizi di localizzazione nelle impostazoni del tuo dispositivo.', 'Servizi di localizzazione disabilitati');
        } 
        else if (error.code==2) {
            showAlert ('Non siamo riusciti a determinare la tua posizione. Riproveremo tra qualche secondo.', 'Posizione non trovata');
        }
        else if (error.code==3) {
            showAlert ('Non siamo riusciti a determinare la tua posizione. Riproveremo tra qualche secondo.', 'Posizione non trovata');
        }
    }


        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="onBodyLoad('map_canvas')">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="height:600px;"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use valid map object in function `setCurrentPosition()` and not just a string: `mapCalled` has to be changed to `homeMap`:

```
myLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: currentposition,
    // map: mapCalled
    map: homeMap
});   
console.log("panning to my location");
// mapCalled.panTo(currentposition);
homeMap.panTo(currentposition);
```

Comment: Thanks Anto! I really needed someone with fresh eyes to spot it.